# How to I start with a remote IP address connected to my computer to the process that has opened the connection?

Tags: security, firewall, ip, netstat, net

If I type "netstat", I can see a list of IP addresses that my PC is connected to.

If I start with an IP address, how do I find the process that has opened the connection to said IP address?

Comment: Which operating system is this on?

Comment: Optionally see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2281/how-do-i-get-a-mapping-of-pid-to-port

Answer (score 1):

I find following command quite convenient

```
netstat -nap --ip
```

Answer (score 0):

1- open cmd > netstat -ano

2- you will see a column says PID with a number

3- open task manager, go to processes tab, and select "view" menu while you are on this tab

4- then choose "select column" and add PID

Now you will see what the PID from the netstat command is bind to

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to use either `lsof` or `fuser`.

`lsof` has an easier syntax, plus it directly shows all relevant info including the process executable name:

```
lsof -i @address
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sockstat -c | grep IP.IP.IP.IP`.

Without grep the output looks like this.

```
USER     COMMAND    PID   FD PROTO  LOCAL ADDRESS         FOREIGN ADDRESS
hennes   sshd       74693 3  tcp4   131.155.141.68:22     88.159.82.134:4748
hennes   sshd       74693 4  stream -> ??
root     sshd       74690 3  tcp4   131.155.141.68:22     88.159.82.134:4748
root     sshd       74690 5  stream -> ??
hennes   ssh        72543 3  tcp6   2001:610:1108:5011::68:637622001:610:1108:5010::159:22
hennes   sshd       84193 3  tcp4   131.155.141.68:22     88.159.82.134:1047
hennes   sshd       84193 4  stream -> ??
root     sshd       84190 3  tcp4   131.155.141.68:22     88.159.82.134:1047
root     sshd       84190 5  stream -> ??
postfix  pickup     84095 7  dgram  -> ??
hennes   tf-50b8    61863 3  tcp6   2001:610:1108:5011::68:612482001:610:1108:5011::70:3333
001:610:1108:5011::68:222001:610:1108:5011:2e0:81ff:fe2d:e87c:54441
root     sshd       75997 3  tcp6   2001:610:1108:5011::68:222001:610:1108:5011:2e0:81ff:fe2d:e87c:54441
root     sshd       75997 5  stream -> ??
hennes   irssi      46812 3  tcp4   131.155.141.68:57245  88.198.94.219:6667
hennes   irssi      46806 3  tcp4   131.155.141.68:56526  131.155.140.178:6667
hennes   ssh        91455 3  tcp6   2001:610:1108:5011::68:543982001:610:1108:5010::135:22
```

With grep you simple filter so it only shows the desired IP, but the header is also lost.